# QGIS python script for algorithm indentation error

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, indentation

I'm working with version python 3.7 and QGIS 3.10.6.

I have create an algorithm with python script but I can't run it, because there is this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 224, in runAlgorithm
exec(self.editor.text(), _locals)
File "", line 17
return "Bufferpointintersect"
^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"

I cheek but I really does not understand where is the problem of indentation.

Look at my screenshot and inform me where do you find the error and suggest the correction.

[Error image indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chxR9.png)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to SO, [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why when I post the code there is written "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

I assume is the error that prevents me by running the script in QGIS. I can't post the script because technically I can't send the answer if I write the script in the message.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a line in your code where you used spaces and another where you used the tab character. If you are using vim, you can do:

```
:%s/\t/    /gc
```

To replace, with confirmation, all the tabulations by 4 spaces.